# Clean up coded ui test

Tags: coded-ui-tests, code-cleanup, data-driven

I created data-driven coded ui test with more iterations. When I run the test and when first iteration is done, I want do put some clean up code before every other iteration to clean all changes that are made in the previous iteration.

Any idea how to do that?

Answer (score 2):

Coded UI tests allow method with the [TestCleanup] attribute. Such methods are run after each test. If you are creating Coded UI test file you should find an example of a [TestCleanup] in comments in the CodedUItestN.cs file.

Methods with [ClassCleanup] and [AssemblyCleanup] attributes are also supported.

This SO question has more information [Test Method that runs once at the Start of the Test?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17969202/test-method-that-runs-once-at-the-start-of-the-test/17969518#17969518)